# Can't log in to WordPress after trying all recommended options

Tags: php, wordpress

A client called complaining that they are unable to log into WordPress to make changes to the site. After looking into the issue I found that all user accounts are unable to log in. Because of this I've followed all the steps outlined [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Login_Trouble) but to no avail.

I attempted to reset the password using WordPress and I never received an email.

I hard reset all users passwords in the database so I know for a fact the passwords I'm using are correct. This still didn't work.

Suspecting it was a plugin I disabled all plugins and tried again. This was a no go.

I disabled all themes and used a fresh new default theme and tested it. This also didn't work.

Suspecting that it's a core file issue since the WordPress site was outdated I replaced the wp-includes and wp-admin folders with the latest versions of the folders. I also updated the main files (wp-config.php, wp-login.php, etc). I tried to log in and it asked me to upgrade the database which I did, and still it says that the password is incorrect.

Has anyone else come across this issue? Can anyone suggest something for me to try to get it to work again?

Comment: What changed recently or since the last time it worked? Did you do any deployment - if yes try to rollback to the previous version. Did you do any upgrade - try to rollback etc. Do you have a sandbox where you can reproduce this?

Comment: >> I hard reset all users passwords in the database... << How did you do this?

Comment: @Paras As far as I know nothing. The version of Wordpress was outdated so I suspect a possible hack since the owner of the site is not very diligent when it comes to updating things. I do not have a sandbox but I have backups of the site when it (may) have still been working that I might be able to use.

Comment: @OpenSourceTrainingRajkot I went to the wp-users table, edited a user, entered a new password and hashed it with md5.

Comment: @A.Williams do you have access of database ? yes then you can create new user from there or else you can change password of admin user as well over there , you need to add new password in password column and then select md5 for opposite side

Comment: @ManthanDave I did not try manually creating a new user however, I did change the admin password using md5.

Comment: @A.Williams Yes try to add new user manually , make sure in user_login field you need add admin and then definitely it will work

Comment: Did your query to reset the password look like the following (if not try it, always works for me): `UPDATE wp_users SET user_pass = MD5( 'new_password' ) WHERE user_login = 'your-username';` assuming your db is prefixed with `wp_`

Comment: If you have FTP access, also try (temporarily) renaming the .htaccess file (in the webroot folder) and then check.

Comment: @ManthanDave I just attempted to add an admin user and that failed.

Comment: @stemie That's pretty much the query I used. Regardless I tried it and that didn't help.

Comment: @A.Williams so what error you are facing ?

Comment: @OpenSourceTrainingRajkot renaming the .htaccess file also didn't work. I double checked to make sure I am editing the live site and my edits appear fine so something is going wrong with either the core files or the database.

Comment: @ManthanDave ERROR: The password you entered for the username "any username" is incorrect. Lost your password?

Comment: @A.Williams i think you are checking another database , have you confirm you have added new user in the same database which your current website using ?

Comment: @ManthanDave Yes the database I am querying is the one that is connected with the site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Make sure to delete this function when you are not using it! It poses a security risk. You have been warned.**

Not sure if you have access to the theme files (ftp) but you can add a user programmatically using the function below. Add it to the end of your functions.php file and then visit the url(see below) with your email and password as parameters.

After saving your functions.php file you would then visit a url in your browser similar to: `yourwebsite.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=so_39902381&email={your email}&password={your password}`

but replacing `{your email}` and `{your password}` and the actual site name with your credentials. 
So for eg. `yourwebsite.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=so_39902381&email=me@myemail.com&password=123`

By visiting the url with your custom parameters the function will be triggered which will create the user account. If it tells you your email is already registered, try a different email.

Add the below code to functions.php in your theme:

```
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_so_39902381', 'so_39902381');
add_action('wp_ajax_so_39902381', 'so_39902381');
/**
* Add a WordPress user programmatically
*/
function so_39902381(){

    $email_address = isset($_GET['email']) ? $_GET['email'] : wp_die();
    $password = isset($_GET['password']) ? $_GET['password'] : wp_die();

    if( null == username_exists( $email_address ) ) {

        // Generate the password and create the user
        $password = wp_generate_password( 12, false );
        $user_id = wp_create_user( $email_address, $password, $email_address );

        // Set the nickname
        wp_update_user(
        array(
          'ID'          =>    $user_id,
          'nickname'    =>    $email_address
        )
        );

        // Set the role
        $user = new WP_User( $user_id );
        $set = $user->set_role( 'administrator' );

        //Email the user
        wp_mail( $email_address, 'Welcome!', 'Your Password: ' . $password );

    } else {
        echo 'error: email already registered, choose another';
    }
    wp_die();
}
```

I suggest you change these logins once you have access to the backend.